# Standalone simple chart not working - highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Here is my highcharts example as taken from http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/ but I receive this error in Chrome :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'highcharts' localhost:8080/spring-hibernate-template/:15
(anonymous function) localhost:8080/spring-hibernate-template/:15
c jquery.js:3048
p.fireWith jquery.js:3160
x.extend.ready jquery.js:433
q
```

I'm importing highcharts & jQuery so this should work ?

Here is my code :

```
<html>
<head>

  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(function () {
     $('#container').highcharts({
         title: {
             text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
             x: -20 //center
         },
         subtitle: {
             text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
             x: -20
         },
         xAxis: {
             categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
         },
         yAxis: {
             title: {
                 text: 'Temperature (°C)'
             },
             plotLines: [{
                 value: 0,
                 width: 1,
                 color: '#808080'
             }]
         },
         tooltip: {
             valueSuffix: '°C'
         },
         legend: {
             layout: 'vertical',
             align: 'right',
             verticalAlign: 'middle',
             borderWidth: 0
         },
         series: [{
             name: 'Tokyo',
             data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
         }, {
             name: 'New York',
             data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
         }, {
             name: 'Berlin',
             data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
         }, {
             name: 'London',
             data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
         }]
     });
 });


 </script>
 <body>


<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the order of your scripts, you're including highcharts before jQuery. Change the order like so:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the jQuery before Highcharts. Highcharts needs it to plug into.